# Free email hosting service

Tags: gratis, web-apps, email

Outlook and gmail used to offer free email hosting, not anymore apparently so I'm searching for alternatives before setting a mail server on my own VPS. My requirements are:

- Free web based hosting service for domain names, at least for like 3 accounts
- supports mail forwarding and alias and all that stuff. Forward incoming mails to gmail, and sending from gmail or whatever.
- Guarantee that it always be free so I don't have to move to another service 2
  months later.
- [The admin should be able reset](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52412/how-could-the-admin-reset-the-password-of-a-user-on-domains-live-com) the password of the users, He should be a real super user

Comment: Please not that this site is about *software,* not *service* recommendation – and specifically hosting requests are off-topic (see: [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/185))

Comment: @Izzy I see, but what I'm looking for is more of a webappp than a traditional hosting

Comment: Not to be a Debbie Downer, but I think you are going to have a hard time with this. I sincerely hope someone can point you in the right direction as far as a web app, etc. but I personally (me, myself and I only) would suck it up and pay for the VPS.

Comment: @Anaksunaman the domain not mine, for a friend, not willing to take responsibility if it got hacked or anything, not not willing to host it on my vps, my vps is mine, besides, configuring mail servers is a pain, making sure that it won't send as spam, and ssl and all that shit, two things really wast my time - configuring bind and setting up a mail server. I don't do that unless I really really really have to

Comment: possibly this question should have been moved to webapps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try [Zoho Mail](https://www.zoho.com/mail/) as they have 5 free users with the possibility to refer people.

Comment: As of 2017, the offer is now with 25 users.